# I have got the following jquery to work in Chrome and FF but not IE(8-11)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I need a double loop so that I can move through my custom tags and grab the options that belong to each drop so that I can build custom objects.
My problem is no matter what i seems to do it won't work in IE.
This is my most recent attempt it work in Chrome FF but Not IE.
**Please help me figure out how to do this in IE**(8-11).(I'm current'y using IE9 to test but will test it in IE8 at some point.)
Thanks in advance

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

 <custom:drop id='c1' style='display:none'>
        <custom:option id='d1'>t2c1</custom:option>
        <custom:option id='d2'>hahahahahah</custom:option>
    </custom:drop>
    <custom:drop id='c2' style='display:none'>
        <custom:option id='d2'>t2c2</custom:option>
    </custom:drop>
    <custom:drop id='c3' style='display:none'>
        <custom:option id='d3'>t2c3</custom:option>
    </custom:drop>
    <custom:drop id='c4' style='display:none'>
        <custom:option id='d4'>t2c4</custom:option>
    </custom:drop>

<script>
$("custom\\:drop").each(function()
{
    var s = "#"+($(this).context.id) + " custom\\:option";
    alert(s);
alert($(s));
    $(s).each(function(){
            alert( $(this).html() );//
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is a JSfiddle: it will work in firefox and chrome but not IE

Comment: "it won't work" is not a good description of your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer is really picky about what is inserted in the DOM. You need to declare the namespace "`custom`" and pre-create the elements `drop` and `option`:

```
<html xmlns:custom="needed for custom elements">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../app/lib/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>      
</head>
<body>
<script>
    // needed to make parse properly
    document.createElement('drop');
    document.createElement('option');
</script>


<custom:drop id='c1' style='display:none'>
    <custom:option id='d1'>t2c1</custom:option>
    <custom:option id='d2'>hahahahahah</custom:option>
</custom:drop>
<custom:drop id='c2' style='display:none'>
    <custom:option id='d2'>t2c2</custom:option>
</custom:drop>
<custom:drop id='c3' style='display:none'>
    <custom:option id='d3'>t2c3</custom:option>
</custom:drop>
<custom:drop id='c4' style='display:none'>
    <custom:option id='d4'>t2c4</custom:option>
</custom:drop>

<script>
    $("custom\\:drop").each(function()
    {
        var s = "#"+($(this).context.id) + " custom\\:option";
        alert(s);
        alert($(s));
        $(s).each(function(){
            alert( $(this).html() );//
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this in IE11 and it worked fine. It will take me a while to open my other VMs to test in IE8, IE9 and IE10. Hope you can confirm us sooner

Comment: It also worked in IE8!!!!!! However I added <!DocType HTML> (as the very first line because IE8) to make sure it would be in standards mode.

Thanks Dalorzo!

Comment: @Crushinator glad to hear it helped you :)